# ColumnSchemaBuilder could not be converted to int while migrating in Yii2

Tags: sql, database, yii2, migration

I'm fixing my migrations and now, after typing `yii migrate`, I got this error:

```
Object of class yii\db\mysql\ColumnSchemaBuilder could not be converted to int
```

I've tested on which exact place the error occurs and it's:

```
        $this->insert('base_auth_item',
        [
            'name' => 'editClientUser',
            'type' => 2,
            'description' => 'test',
            'rule_name' => null,
            'module' => 4,
            'data' => null,
            'created_at' => $this->integer(11)->defaultValue(0),
            'updated_at' => $this->integer(11)->defaultValue(0),
        ]
    );
```

Could someone explain me where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
'created_at' => $this->integer(11)->defaultValue(0),
'updated_at' => $this->integer(11)->defaultValue(0),
```

Change this to real values, for now they are column definitions.

Comment: Hm, interesting, but how can I know the real values if I don't know when it is created or updated? Every time I'm creating or updating it, the time will be different.

Comment: For example by php function `time()`?

Comment: So instead of `'created_at' => $this->integer(11)->defaultValue(0),` it should be `'created_at => 'timestamp()'`? Btw, thanks for the answer

Comment: `'created_at => 'time()'`

Comment: But I need timestamp, coz in every other table those fields are timestamp:)

Comment: `time()` returns timestamp.